# What is the best density for creating mesh deform cages?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging

I'm trying to figure out wich density for the mesh is the best for a mesh deformer cage that will be used in a armature rig.
But the way that I found is pretty slow(remodeling again and again the mesh cage) to discover this.

Someone with a bit more experience can tell-me wich density worked better for you?[image: my try]